# Geolocating IP Address in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, ip-geolocation

I am developing an windows 8 app in C# 
And want to get Geo Coordinates of IP addresses
or
Want an API that can exactly or nearly geolocate the IP address in windows 8 app!
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 14):

Just use a web service here is free one 10000 requests per hour

http://freegeoip.net/static/index.html

REST Call [http://freegeoip.net/xml/[your ip]](http://freegeoip.net/xml/%5Byour%20ip%5D)

**EDIT**

Simple code to download from a url

```
using (var objClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var strFile = objClient.DownloadString("http://freegeoip.net/xml/192.168.0.1");
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
I think it would be helpful but i am new at API integration
so would you please provide me complete code or some guide how to use it!

Comment: added some simple code you need to change the ip accordingly then process the result.

Comment: Good solution +1. But based on (freegeoip) *you're allowed up to 10,000 queries per hour by default.* I edited your post to fix the queries count.

Comment: The link redirects to commercial service, their free tier is now 10 000 req/month

Answer (score -1):

If you type your question in any web search engine, this page is bound to come up: [Windows 8 Geolocation sample in C#, VB.NET, C++, JavaScript for Visual Studio 2012](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66). Download it, look at it, I'm sure it's helpful.

Comment: Thanks brother! but that code give us the location from which it is called but i need geolocation for IPs given by me