# how to create a code for IP-address locator which takes IP-address from a table in database

Tags: sql-server, database, geolocation

I am working on a project that collects the Ip address of user and store them into a database.
I would like to know methods or ways i could track these ip's and produce their geographical latitude and longitude details.
I dont want to create a website or an app..i just want it to work locally on my system.

Comment: [Geolocate an IP without extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385264/geolocate-an-ip-without-extensions)
[Geolocation IP in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138071/geolocation-ip-in-java)
[IP GeoLocation in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196962/ip-geolocation-in-vb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you could do directly in T-SQL However you could use CLR with C#

```
using (var objClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var strFile = objClient.DownloadString("http://freegeoip.net/xml/192.168.0.1");
}
```

See [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959305/geolocating-ip-address-in-c-sharp)